# SparkFun nRF52832 Breakout + SPI display

Tags: spi, nrf52

I'm using the **TFT display ILI9341** linked to the Adafruit HUZZAH through SPI with the example skecth provided "graphictest" and everythings works fine.

```
// HUZZAH           DEVICE     Spakfun nRf52
// Violet -- 12 -->  MISO  <-- 12 -- Violet
// Rouge  -- 3V -->  LED   <-- 3V3-- Orange
// Vert   -- 14 -->  SCK   <-- 13 -- Vert
// Bleu   -- 13 -->  MOSI  <-- 11 -- Bleu
// Blanc #-- 4  -->  D/C   <-- 9  -- Marron
// Bleu   -- 3V -->  RESET <-- 3v3-- Gris
// Blanc o-- 5  -->  CS    <-- 10 -- Jaune
// Noir   -- GND-->  GND   <-- GND-- Noir
// Rouge  -- 3V -->  VCC   <-- 3V3-- Vcc
```

I want to do the same things with the **SparkFun nRF52832 Breakout** but the sketch stop during "tft.begin()"

```
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("ILI9341 Test!"); 

  tft.begin();
```

I also checked the header : variant.h

```
/*
 * SPI Interfaces
 */

#define SPI_INTERFACES_COUNT 1

#define PIN_SPI_MISO         (12)
#define PIN_SPI_MOSI         (11)
#define PIN_SPI_SCK          (13)

static const uint8_t SS   = 10 ;
static const uint8_t MOSI = PIN_SPI_MOSI ;
static const uint8_t MISO = PIN_SPI_MISO ;
static const uint8_t SCK  = PIN_SPI_SCK ;
```

I try to use SDcard slot built-in on the ILI9341 display, it's fine with HUZZAH but KO with Sparkfun nRf52.

If some of you could help me, it would be very kind.

Thanks.